# How to use ANSI color codes to print colored text to bash terminal from a file?

Tags: bash, ansi-colors

I have a file (file.txt) like this:

```
Yes
Yes
No
No
```

and I want to output this file to a bash terminal with "Yes" as green and "No" as red. I have written the following script:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'

cat file.txt | sed 's/No/${RED}No${NC}/g' | sed 's/Yes/${GREEN}Yes${NC}/g' > color_file.txt

printf "$(cat color_file.txt)"
```

The output looks like this:

```
${GREEN}Yes${NC}
${GREEN}Yes${NC}
${RED}No${NC}
${RED}No${NC}
```

Instead of being colored.

The coloring works if I have a script like:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
printf "${RED}No${NC}"
```

How would I read a file, color its contents and then print to the terminal?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here. As far as I can tell my quotes are not the issue (I may well be wrong, but I am fairly new). The problem is that I am unsure how to make `printf` read the contents of the file and therefore execute the commands within it.

Comment: `As far as I can tell my quotes are not the issue` Your quotes are the issue. `'` differ from `"`. Research the difference between them. Also `\033` (4 characters, ```\``` `0` `3` `3`) are special for `printf`, but not for `sed`. `printf "$(cat color_file.txt)"` why would you `printf $(..)`? Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I read a file, color its contents and then print to the terminal?

You could leave the expansions in the file and replace the `${...}` forms with the variables when reading the file:

```
RED=$'\E[0;31m'
NC=$'\E[0m'
GREEN=$'\E[0;32m'
sed 's/No/${RED}No${NC}/g ; s/Yes/${GREEN}Yes${NC}/g' file.txt > color_file.txt
( export RED NC GREEN ; envsubst color_file.txt )
```

But I believe you wanted to actually output the escape sequences into the file:

```
RED=$'\E[0;31m'
NC=$'\E[0m'
GREEN=$'\E[0;32m'
sed "s/No/${RED}No${NC}/g ; s/Yes/${GREEN}Yes${NC}/g" file.txt > color_file.txt
cat color_file.txt
```

Or maybe you wanted `printf` to interpret the escpe sequences in the content of a file:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
sed "s/No/${RED}No${NC}/g ; s/Yes/${GREEN}Yes${NC}/g" file.txt > color_file.txt
printf "%b\n" "$(cat color_file.txt)"
# or maybe:
xargs -0 printf "%b" < color_file.txt
# or maybe:
sed 's/\\033/\e/g' color_file.txt 
# etc.
```

---

Check your scripts with shellcheck - it will tell you about all mistakes that you did.

> ```
> 's/No/${RED}...'
> ```

Variable expansion does not expand within single quotes.

> ```
> #If you would:
> RED='\033[0;31m'
> .... sed "....${RED}..."
> ```

`sed` does not interpret octal escape sequences. For `sed` the string `\033` is a zero byte 0x00 followed by two `33`.

> ```
> printf "$(cat ...)"
> ```

Is an antipattern. Just execute `cat ...`.

> ```
> cat ... | sed..
> ```

Is a useless use of cat.

> how to make printf read the content of the file

It is not possible to read a file with `printf`. It's not a tool for that.

> and therefore execute the commands within it.

This feels unrelated to your issue, but to execute a file just call it with an interpreter `sh ./file.sh` or source it within current execution environment `. ./file.sh`.

Comment: Thank you outputting the escape sequences to the file worked perfectly  :)

I will use shellcheck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a handy bash function to colorize text without having to remember cryptic ANSI escapes or what values map to what numbers. Using it:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Map color names to terminfo setaf/setab codes.
declare -A colors=( [black]=0 [red]=1 [green]=2 [yellow]=3 [blue]=4
                    [magenta]=5 [cyan]=6 [white]=7 )

# colorize colorname text
# Returns text wrapped in ANSI color tags. Unknown color names are mapped to white.
colorize() {
    printf "%s%s%s" "$(tput setaf "${colors[$1]:-7}")" "$2" "$(tput op)"
}

greenyes=$(colorize green Yes)
redno=$(colorize red No)
sed -e "s/Yes/$greenyes/g" -e "s/No/$redno/g" file.txt
```

will print the colorized `file.txt` to standard output. You can redirect to a different file, or do both at once by piping it to `tee`, or whatever else you want.